# Do I need a Storage Controller for all my model classes in the app to use azure file sync?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-files

**Background:**

- Xamrin Forms Client App
- Azure backend with Dot Net
- Using Azure offline data sync
- trying to use Azure offline File Sync

**Related SO questions** 
there have been 2 more questions I asked here which are somewhat related 
[Getting a 404 while using Azure File Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575825/getting-resource-not-found-error-while-using-azure-file-sync/)

[Getting a 500 while using Azure File Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659428/getting-a-server-error-500-as-soon-as-file-sync-is-used-in-xamarin-forms-app)

**Solution** 
As stated above in the first link, I had to create a storage controller for the User entity to be able to successfully login even though I do not intend to use Files for Users.

As I work further in the app, I am still getting more 404 errors as I can see in fiddler. These are similar calls which are looking to access an API like below

*GET /tables/{EntityName}/{Id}/MobileServ‌​iceFiles HTTP/1.1*

**My Question Now**
Do I need a storage controller for every entity I have in my solution? may be every entity that inherits from EntityData?

Is there a way I can selectively tell the system which entities are going to work with files & have storage controllers only for them? Like, may be, marking them with some Attribute?

**Reference**
I am using [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/) blog post to implement Azure File Sync in my app.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own query (and not the answer I wanted to hear) YES. We need a Storage controller for all entities, even if they don't have any files to be stored in Storage account. This is a limitation. 
Found this info on comments of the original blog I was following (I wish I did it earlier), to quote the author

> Donna Malayeri [donnam@MSFT]  Chris • 2 months ago
>   It's a limitation of the current storage SDK that you can't specify which tables have files. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure...
>
> As a workaround, you have to make your own file sync trigger factory.
>   Here's a sample: https://github.com/azure-appse...
>
> The reason the SDK calls Get/Delete for files in the storage
>   controller is because the server manages the mapping from record to
>   container or blob name. You wouldn't necessarily want to give the
>   client access to the blob account to access arbitrary files or
>   containers, for instance. In the case of delete, the server doesn't
>   even need to give out a SAS token with delete permissions, since it
>   can just authenticate the user and do the delete itself.